# Convert big dataset from .txt to .arff format

Tags: weka, arff

I have big dataset about 1 GB that I need to convert from `.txt` to `.arff` format. All sources convert from `.txt` to `.csv` and then to `.arff` but with online converter the max size is 100 MB. Any one help me how to convert this 1 GB data?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert txt file to csv with this snippet.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Convert {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Initialize ...");
    Read read = new Read("soal01.txt");
    Print print = new Print();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        try{
            print.setFileName("jawaban"+i+".csv");
            read.setPrint(print);
            read.exec(i);
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Finished");
   }
}

class Print {

protected String fileName;

protected FileWriter writer;

public Print() {}

public Print(String fileName) throws IOException {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.writer = new FileWriter(this.fileName);
}

public String getFileName() {
    return this.fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) throws IOException {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.writer = new FileWriter(this.fileName);
}

public void close() throws IOException {
    this.writer.flush();
    this.writer.close();
}

public void addRow(String[] c) throws IOException {
    int l = c.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        this.writer.append(c[i]);
        if(i != (l - 1)) {
            this.writer.append(",");
        }
    }
    this.writer.append('\n');
  }
}

class Read {

protected String fileName;

protected BufferedReader bufferedReader;

protected Print print;

public Read(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public Read(Print print, String fileName) {
    this.print = print;
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public void setPrint(Print print) {
    this.print = print;
}

public Print getPrint() {
    return this.print;
}

public void exec(Integer type) {
    String sCurrentLine = "";
    try{
        this.bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(this.fileName));

        while((sCurrentLine = this.bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] columns = sCurrentLine.split("\t");
            int length = columns.length;
            if(type == 1) {
                this.print.addRow(columns);
            } else if(length >= 2){
                double col1 = Double.parseDouble(columns[1]);
                if(col1 > 20){
                    if(type == 2){
                        this.print.addRow(columns);
                    } else if(type == 3 && length >= 3 && columns[2] != null){
                        this.print.addRow(columns);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this.print.close();

    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try{
            if(this.bufferedReader != null) {
                this.bufferedReader.close();
            }
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks man for your help but i run the code and the following error appear. 



 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Teenagers Share How Christianity Affects Their Lives"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at Read.exec(Convert.java:97)
 at Convert.main(Convert.java:12)